# Which distribution fits my data in Python

Tags: python, distributions

I am trying to find a distribution for my data. It seems like lognormal distribution. But I am not able to fit it correctly, at least that's what I think.

The data consists of [time to return an product] in days. See the graphs below.

How can I properly test the distribution of my data and make profound conclusions?

[image: barchart]
[image: histogram plot]

Comment: what did you try yourself? 
A very quick search gives something like this for example
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html
this might be useful?

Comment: Could be log-normal, could be gamma (or chi2 which is gamma as well), could be F-distribution. If you cannot pick distribution from domain knowledge, you have to try several of them and check goodness of fit (like K-S test proposed by @Chrisvdberge)

Comment: Your desired "profound conclusions" rarely arises from data alone.  Is there some theoretical basis for a particular family of distributions?  If not, then the best you can do is have a relatively compact description (rather than explanation) of your data.